# MongoDate structure in PHP - JSON output

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I am currently using MongoDb for an API I am developing. I am trying to figure out what is the  sec and usec property represents in a MongoDate object in PHP.

When I json_encode my output I get the MongoDate interpreted as

```
created: {
    sec: 1351294929,
    usec: 564000
}
```

What I want to know is what does "sec" and "usec" represent exactly. In this case "created" is the timestamp when the document is made but does 'sec' represent the Unix timestamp format in seconds? Then what does "usec" represent?

And is it fine to leave the output like this and JS handles intepretation or should I reformat this in the PHP side to a YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[MongoDate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php)**

`$sec` is **Number of seconds**

`$usec` is **Microseconds**

For showing a human readable `MongoDate`, you can use something like this:

```
date('Y-M-d h:i:s', $yourDate->sec);
```

Comment: And this was what I found to convert the MongoDate object in Javascript
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029955/json-date-explanation

Answer (score 0):

According this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341234/php-and-mongodate-query), it appears your date column has been converted to a non-date type object. MongoDates should not look this way.